# Shorter if statement in Javascript

Tags: javascript, object, if-statement

I'm newbe in Js I wanna check to statuses have same value:

```
if (data.a_status == 'approved' && data.b_status == 'approved' && data.c_status == 'approved')
```

Can I write this shorter? I can't find any material how to check same value in three variables

Comment: You could do `["a_status", "b_status", "c_status"].every(k => data[k] === "approved")` if you have many properties. But this will need a second glance to understand what's going on. If it's just 3 properties, your code is much more readable

Comment: no I have more values in data, but I wanna check only this 3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you know the exact properties you want to access from data, put them into an array and access them via square bracket notation within an `every` loop against the data Object.

```js
const data = {
  a_status : 'approved', 
  b_status : 'approved', 
  c_status : 'approved',
  foo: 'bar',
  hello: 'world'
}

const statuses = ['a_status', 'b_status', 'c_status']

const approved = statuses.every(s => data[s] === 'approved')

console.log(approved)
```